# Run one query for two different tables

Tags: sql

I want to run some queries which can help me to get result:

I am new  for SQL

I have two different tables `Item` and `ItemDynamic`. In the `Item` table I have the columns `ItemLookUpcode`, `ItemID` and `Total Quantity`. In the `Item Dynamic` table I have the columns `ItemID` (same as Item table) and `Quantity`, `StoreID`.

I want a result as in one table which can give me `ItmLookupCode` and `Quantity` (`Item.Quantity - ItemDynamic.Qunatity`)

I have tried some queries but not worked out please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and explain where you are having difficulties.

Comment: In line with Oded's comment, check out joins, specifically inner joins between two tables.   Use that information to construct something and post it here.

Comment: Show us what you have, and tell us **what database** you're using! (including which version)

Comment: "I want to result as in one table" - Are you looking at making a 3rd table which displays "ItmLookupCode and Quantity (Item.Quantity - ItemDynamic.Qunatity) " ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) as in the following code

```
SELECT Item.ItemLookupCode, ItemDynamic.Quantity
FROM Item INNER JOIN ItemDynamic 
ON Item.ItemID=ItemDynamic.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

The Query should be like,

```
SELECT Item.ItemLookUpcode, (Item.Quantity - ItemDynamic.Qunatity) as Quantity
FROM Item, ItemDynamic
WHERE Item.ItemID = ItemDynamic.ItemID
```

For more on SQL Query you can visit to http://ektaraval.blogspot.com/search/label/SQL%20Server

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you need is a join:

```
SELECT 
  ItemLookUpcode, (i.Quantity - d.Quantity) as Quantity
FROM Item i, ItemDynamic d
WHERE
   i.ItemID = d.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create a new table, try creating a view. Views aren't actually tables, but can be used very much like them!

So, try;

```
CREATE VIEW myItemView 
as 
  SELECT 
     Item.ItemLookupCode
     ,(Item.Quantity - ItemDynamic.Quantity as Quantity
  FROM Item 
  INNER JOIN ItemDynamic ON Item.ItemID=ItemDynamic.ItemID
```

Then, you should be able to select * from myitemview to get what you're looking for.